# Let $A,B$ be two $n\times n $ matrices each having $\text{rank}=n$. Then $\text{rank}A^3B^2A=n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is this statement true/false?If true prove it if false then give a counter example.

Let $A,B$ be two $n\times n $ matrices each having $\text{rank}=n$.
Then $\text{rank}A^3B^2A=n$.

I tried various examples where I am getting the result to be true.
Also I am unable to prove the result.What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several essentially equivalent ways to solve this problem. Here are two possible approaches:

1. An $n\times n$ matrix has rank $n$ if and only if its kernel is zero. So it's enough to show that the kernel of $A^3B^2A$ is zero.
2. An $n\times n$ matrix has rank $n$ if and only if its determinant is non-zero. And what is the determinant of $A^3B^2A$ in terms of the determinants of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: $\det A^3B^2A=(\det A)^3(\det B)^2\det A\neq 0$

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

**Major hint:**

If $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix of rank $n$ then it is both injective and surjective: [see a proof here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1891627/relationship-between-columns-rows-rank-given-a-system-of-linear-equations/1891667#1891667).

In otherwords, it is bijective.  That is to say in more common words, it is an [**invertible matrix**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix).

Similarly $B$, also being an $n\times n$ matrix of rank $n$, is *also* an invertible matrix.

In fact, we know that *any invertible matrix of size $n\times n$* will also be of rank $n$.

Will the matrix in question, $A^3B^2A$ be invertible?  Not invertible?  Do we not know?

> Is the product of two invertible matrices invertible?  If $E$ and $F$ are invertible, what is $(EF)(F^{-1}E^{-1})=$?